# Python unicode-escape: use only \uNNNN codes, no \xNN

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, escaping

Using Python, I need to encode a Unicode string to a mix of printable ASCII characters and Unicode escape sequences. There is `str.encode('unicode-escape')` for that. Thing is, this conversion outputs hex escape sequences (`\xAB`) for short Unicode sequences and Unicode sequences (`\uABCD`) for longer ones:

```
>>> test = 'XüX → YœYö'
>>> test.encode('unicode-escape')
b'X\\xfcX \\u2192 Y\\u0153Y\\xf6
#    NOPE   OKAY     OKAY    NOPE
```

Are you aware of some Python internal that would *only output **Unicode** escape sequences*?

---

Of course I could manually check if the char can be ASCII printed and otherwise do the conversion myself, but this feels really hackish:

```
>>> coded = ''.join(
        (c if c.encode('ascii', 'ignore') != b''
           else '\\u{:04x}'.format(ord(c)))
        for c in test)
>>> coded
'X\\u00fcX \\u2192 Y\\u0153Y\\u00f6'
#   OKAY     OKAY     OKAY    OKAY
>>> ast.literal_eval("'{}'".format(coded))
'XüX → YœYö'
```

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: The code samples I gave should give you a hint: that's Python 3 code. To answer your question, I would be interested in a solution for both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json

print(json.dumps(u'XüX → YœYö'))
# -> "X\u00fcX \u2192 Y\u0153Y\u00f6"
```

Comment: Speaking about hacks! But this should works, thanks. AFAIK any JSON string is a valid Python string. It would be nice if this assertion could be fact checked, though.

Comment: @Zopieux: the correct way to read the JSON text back in Python: `s = json.loads(json_text)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know, thanks. I will not have to read them back in Python actually, this will be used in code generation.

Comment: Any JSON string literal is a valid Python string literal, but not necessarily one representing the exact same sequence of characters, depending on how surrogates are handled...